# Turn integers (NOT string) separated by comma into array JS

Tags: arrays, numbers, integer

it seems a pretty easy question but I can't find a solution.
I need to turn the argument of this function (just numbers followed by a comma) into an array full of numbers. The problem is, the argument is not a string and I cannot add the `""` to it. If I `console.log([card])` only the first number appears into the array (the 2)... I tried to do a loop but it didn't work out. 
Thanks for the help!

```
function cc(card) {

}
cc(2,3,4,5,6);
```

Comment: You are not sending one single argument. When you do `cc(2,3,4,5,6);` you are sending 5 different argument. You are seeing only the first argument because JS is very perimissible and won't complain if you send a different amount of argument that what it is suposed to receive

Comment: Ok I understand... so is there a way to use all the numbers in that "list"?

Comment: Does your function needs to be able to receive any amount of parameters?

Comment: about five of them, as in the example. However, if there isn't a way of addressing all numbers simply because I am not allowing the function to call them, it might be simply a problem of poor description of the exercise I am doing. Thanks for your help mate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, just in case, you can use the `arguments` variable:

`var cc = function () {
  console.log(arguments)
}`

`cc(1,2,3,4,5)` prints `Arguments { 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 5, … }` and `cc(2,3,4,5,6,7,8)` prints `Arguments { 0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, … }`

Source: https://gomakethings.com/getting-an-array-of-all-arguments-passed-into-a-function-with-vanilla-javascript/

Comment: thanks so much, I didn't know of this method, very useful!!

Comment: and just to add one more thing I just discovered, to end up with an array filled with the arguments, you can also do ``Object.values(arguments)`` , using the method ``Object.values()`` plus the above mentioned ``arguments`` . Very good stuff indeed!